# Twilio Voice hava script sdk, When dial we can send param But how to send Authorization key in the header?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node

I have referred to the standard Twilio example to make a call from the browser, I was able to implement calling.

```
      const call = await device.connect({ params });
```

where params are the body of the post request, But is there any way where we can attach a header to this post request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Using the SDK to start a call isn't an HTTP request. It results in a webhook request from Twilio to your application, but that is different to the initial request from the SDK. You can use the SDK to pass POST request parameters as you have seen, but you cannot pass headers.

If you are trying to pass an Authorization header, then I assume you are trying to ensure that only requests from Twilio are accepted by your application. There's already a way to do this.

Twilio sends an `X-Twilio-Signature` header with each webhook request. The signature is made up of the contents of the request signed with your Twilio auth token. You can read [how this works in depth here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests).

Alternatively, you can add `username:password@` to the start of the webhook URL and Twilio will authenticate via [HTTP authentication](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#http-authentication).